# What is the actual perpose of this users.settings.sendAs.list() API And how to get the data from it?

Tags: node.js, optimization, google-api, gmail-api

working on some node js project and suddenly this api comes up but i don't have any idea about it like how it is working and what are the other approaches to do the same 

Code :

```
 const gmail = google.gmail(`v1`);
 gmail.users.settings.sendAs.list(params, (err, response) => {

            if (err) {
                console.log("errrrrrrrr", err);
                reject(constants.responseMessages.ERROR_GETTING_EMAIL_MESSAGES);
            }
            else {
                var aliases = [];
                response = response.sendAs;
                
                var ignoreOwnerMail = 1;
                if (deviceType) {
                    if (deviceType == 1 || deviceType == 2) {
                        ignoreOwnerMail = 0;
                        if (response.length > ignoreOwnerMail) {
                            return emailData(response).then(res=>{
                                for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                                    aliases.push({
                                        email: response[i].sendAsEmail,
                                        replyto: response[i].replyToAddress,
                                        name: response[i].displayName,
                                        alias: response[i].treatAsAlias,
                                        url : res[i],
                                        signature : response[i].signature
                                    })
                                }
                                resolve(aliases);   
                            }).catch(err=>{
                                console.log(err);    
                            });
                        }
                        }else{
                            resolve(aliases);
                        }
                }
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if(response[i].isDefault == true ){
                    aliasDetails.defaultSignature = response[i].signature || ""
                }
                if (response.length > ignoreOwnerMail) {
                aliases.push({
                    email: response[i].sendAsEmail,
                    replyto: response[i].replyToAddress,
                    name: response[i].displayName,
                    alias: response[i].treatAsAlias,
                    signature : response[i].signature
                })
            }
            }
            
            aliasDetails.aliasArr = aliases;
            return resolve(aliasDetails);
            }
        }

        )
```

So, i checked the official site for the information 
[link of official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list)
In the documentation it is showing only one parameter which is user_id but here in the code it takes one function as well (i am new to node js so, i don't have much knowledge on this) so, why it takes that function and how can i do it in better way because this takes 1s of time and i don't know why.

so, if anyone can guide through this will be very helpful.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The method `users.settings.sendAs.list` lists all existing for a given user. What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: I am reviewing the code and this part comes i don't know  what it actually does and how it does, i printed the outout in the console it returns sendAs object and than the function performs some action on it.

Comment: Is this your code?

Comment: actually from where i am working

Comment: @ziganotschka Is there any other alternative for this api ? if you know please mention it over here.

Comment: To know if there is an alternative, you wqould need to explain better what exactly you would like to achieve.

Comment: okay so, this api actually return the list of aliases for the given user_id (which is email address) with user_id we have to give oauth2client token [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) you can refer it from mentioned link, and whatever the content of the function is perform on the response return by this gmail api but the time taken for the response is huge sometimes 4-5s so, that's the problem.

Comment: There is no different api per se, but you can implement [batching requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to speed up execution.

Comment: There is no different api per se, but you can implement [batching requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to speed up execution.